# Search response from Marklogic with all matching documents

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

When I do basic search using the REST API using http://localhost:8003/v1/search?q=harry&format=json, I get a result from MarkLogic with all documents containing harry.

```
{
  "snippet-format": "snippet",
  "total": 2,
  "start": 1,
  "page-length": 10,
  "results": [
    {
      "index": 1,
      "uri": "/store/books/children/c1",
      "path": "fn:doc(\"/store/books/children/c1\")",
      "score": 16384,
      "confidence": 0.5254987,
      "fitness": 0.6964535,
      "href": "/v1/documents?uri=%2Fstore%2Fbooks%2Fchildren%2Fc1",
      "mimetype": "application/xml",
      "format": "xml",
      "matches": [
        {
          "path": "fn:doc(\"/store/books/children/c1\")/book/title",
          "match-text": [
            {
              "highlight": "Harry"
            },
            " Potter"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "index": 2,
      "uri": "/store/books/children/c2",
      "path": "fn:doc(\"/store/books/children/c2\")",
      "score": 16384,
      "confidence": 0.5254987,
      "fitness": 0.6964535,
      "href": "/v1/documents?uri=%2Fstore%2Fbooks%2Fchildren%2Fc2",
      "mimetype": "application/xml",
      "format": "xml",
      "matches": [
        {
          "path": "fn:doc(\"/store/books/children/c2\")/book/title",
          "match-text": [
            {
              "highlight": "Harry"
            },
            " Potter Part 1"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "qtext": "harry",
  "metrics": {
    "query-resolution-time": "PT0.0038395S",
    "snippet-resolution-time": "PT0.001753S",
    "total-time": "PT0.0068583S"
  }
}
```

But I want the response to not just contain the information of document but to return the document as well. So that I don't have to do separate calls to get the documents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by setting the [`Accept` header](http://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/REST/GET/v1/search#Accept) to `multipart/mixed`. If you want the search response as well as the matching documents, set the [`view=results`](http://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/REST/GET/v1/search#view?) request parameter.

See the following for more details:
http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/bulk#id_65903

Answer (score 0):

In case `multipart/mixed` happens to be not an option (perhaps because you consume the response in the browser), you could also look at using [`<extract-document-data selected="all"/>`](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/appendixa#id_44222), potentially combined with a transform that converts XML to JSON for processing convenience ([extractedToJson.sjs](https://github.com/marklogic/slush-marklogic-node/blob/master/app/templates/rest-api/transforms/extractedToJson.sjs) would be a good example for that).

Note though that including the actual documents can severely slow down transfer of search results, particularly if the documents are large.

HTH!